# COUNTING results per row in self referenced table

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table called Clients. And at this table, I have an `idFather` to know who added this row to the table.

Sample:

```
id | user    | idFather | createdAt
---+---------+----------+-----------
01 | raphael | null     | 01-06-2016
02 | jose    | 01       | 03-06-2016
03 | ryan    | 01       | 02-06-2016
04 | alyssa  | 03       | 04-06-2016
```

I'm trying to count how many clients each client invited to the system this month.

I'm using this query to count, but I'm doing the counting using PHP. I want to do it in MySQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client
    WHERE idFather = 1
    AND MONTH(createdAt) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

For now, I'm doing it like this:

Get all results from database, and for each client, executing the query above. I'm looking to execute a query and get it counted from the database without the need look at each one with PHP. Today I have just 60 clients in the table, but next month, it can be 1 thousand, or more. It will not work properly with php.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
I'm looking to get a query result like this:

```
id | user    | idFather | createdAt  | totalInvited
---+---------+----------+------------+-------------
01 | raphael | null     | 01-06-2016 | 2     
02 | jose    | 01       | 03-06-2016 | 0
03 | ryan    | 01       | 02-06-2016 | 1
04 | alyssa  | 03       | 04-06-2016 | 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is on the right track but needs several adjustments to be correct and efficient:

- The `INNER JOIN` will only give you clients with 1 or more children, not the ones with 0 children. You need an outer join for that: `client c LEFT JOIN client p ...`
- If there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `client (user)`, then the group by is ok. Otherwise you may have 2 users with same name (but different id). To differentiate them, `GROUP BY c.id, c.user` is needed, which is not bad to have anyway for efficiency.
- The date math and conditions are not entirely correct, will fail on January dates. They need correction. Even better to make the conditions sargable so indexes on `createdAt` may be used.
- If the date conditoins are to be checking the children `createdAt` timestamps, then they need to be move to the `ON` clause.

The query improved with all the above points:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(p.idFather) AS totalInvited,
    c.user AS clientName
FROM client c
  LEFT JOIN client p 
    ON  p.idFather = c.id 
    AND p.createdAt >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND p.createdAt  < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY c.id, c.user
ORDER BY totalInvited DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with this Query:

I know its not perfect, but works like a charm...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(p.user) AS totalInvited,
    c.user AS clientName
FROM client p 
INNER JOIN client c ON p.idFather = c.id 
WHERE MONTH(p.createdAt) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND YEAR(p.createdAt) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY clientName
ORDER BY totalInvited DESC
```

Hope it helps someone else...

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct after24 hours - might also help others. You don't get points though! :-(

Comment: You will have problems with your year / month logic in January.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
select 
a.id,
a.user,
a.idFather,
a.createdAt,
(select count(id) from client t where t.idFather = a.id and month(t.createdAt) = month(a.createdAt)) as cnt
from client a
where month(a.createdAt) = month(curdate()) ;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained a few details to the poster of the question..

Comment: @RLF I thought it's a simple query so i did not explain each line of the query. And i did not use year filtering in this query, for that he can use one more filter condition along with month like where year(a.createdAt) = year(curdate()).

Comment: The point of my comment was:  You just offered code without any explanation.  This will greatly reduce the likelihood that your answer will receive much attention.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add `HAVING totalInvited > 0` to the accepted improved answer. There's no need to return rows with no invite.

Below will be the complete query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(p.idFather) AS totalInvited,
    c.user AS clientName
FROM client c
  LEFT JOIN client p 
    ON  p.idFather = c.id 
    AND p.createdAt >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND p.createdAt  < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY c.id, c.user
HAVING totalInvited > 0
ORDER BY totalInvited DESC;
```

I hope the simple modification helps someone.